# Optional yield or return in python3. How to?

Tags: python, python-3.x, return, generator, yield

I would like to have a function that can, optionally, return or yield the result.
Here is an example.

```
def f(option=True):
    ...
    for...:
        if option:
            yield result
        else:
            results.append(result)

    if not option:
        return results
```

Of course, this doesn't work, I have tried with python3 and I always get a generator no matter what option value I set.
As far I have understood, python checks the body of the function and if a `yield` is present, then the result will be a generator.
Is there any way to get around this and make a function that can return or yield at will?

Comment: Why do you need this? Can't you just always use it as a generator and only have it yield once `if not option`?

Comment: Is it an [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)? Could you elaborate more on a problem you are trying to solve here?

Comment: I have a function that extract data from files, I need the data to be a list most of the time but sometimes (in case of big files for example) a generator version of this function could be useful. Of course I can iterate over the generator and make a list but I would really prefer to just ad little extra functionality instead. If I yield only once, it will give me only one item of the list, not all the list and that is not what I want

Comment: @alec_djinn: then use `list(f())` to pull in all values from the generator.

Comment: This would give me the right result but will not add that functionality on my function.

Comment: @MartijnPieters, also the returned value of f() is different from list(f()) in case f() return an iterator. list() adds one more square-bracket-pair to it... Not a big deal of course, but it is an extra thing to take care...

Comment: @alec_djinn: from your other comment it seems you are yielding just one value. In which case `next(f())` would do.

Comment: @alec_djinn: you are not at all clear as to what you want to do here; why would you build a generator that only yields one value, always? There is no point in such a generator, you'd just always use `return` for that case.

Comment: @MartijnPieters, I see your point... I still need to work on it then. Of course like it is now it makes no sense... I'll update it soon

Comment: @alec_djinn: your last edit (since reverted), yielded or returned the function object. There was absolutely no point in that; first because yielding just one object is pointless, you should just return it (unless you always need an iterable, and you have other functions that yield a variable number of elements), and because yielding a function object does nothing to make that function switch between a generator and something that returns a list of elements.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Yes, I got that, stupid me! The problem is getting more complicated of course. What I really want is to return a full list or yield the items of a list while it is generated and I would like to have this option within the same function.

Comment: @alec_djinn: then my answer applies in full. You can't have that. Use a wrapper function like I did (and use `list()` instead of `next()`). But it's much better just to use `list(f())` wherever you wanted to get a list of all the values.

Comment: @MartijnPieters. Yes, I agree.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can't. *Any* use of `yield` makes the function a generator.

You could wrap your function with one that uses `list()` to store all values the generator produces in a list object and returns that:

```
def f_wrapper(option=True):
    gen = f()
    if option:
        return gen    # return the generator unchanged
    return list(gen)  # return all values of the generator as a list
```

However, generally speaking, this is *bad design*. Don't have your functions alter behaviour like this; stick to one return type (a generator *or* an object) and don't have it switch between the two.

Consider splitting this into two functions instead:

```
def f():
    yield result

def f_as_list():
    return list(f())
```

and use either `f()` if you need the generator, and `f_as_list()` if you want to have a list instead.

Since `list()`, (and `next()` to access just one value of a generator) are built-in functions, you rarely need to use a wrapper. Just call those functions directly:

```
# access elements one by one
gen = f()
one_value = next(gen)

# convert the generator to a list
all_values = list(f())
```

Answer (score 1):

What about this?

```
def make_f_or_generator(option):
    def f():
        return "I am a function."
    def g():
        yield "I am a generator."
    if option:
        return f
    else:
        return g
```

This gives you at least the choice to create a function or a generator.

Comment: This is an intriguing idea... It is not clean as I would like it to be, but definitely it  allows me to get 'return' and 'yield' at will simply changing 'option'. I am testing it...

Comment: Worked as I wanted! Thank you. One little modification, should be return f() / return g() (with parenthesis)

Comment: @alec_djinn: you do realise that my `next(generator())` option I proposed does exactly that, right?

Comment: @MartijnPieters Not really, why do you think I shall use next() instead? I am updating the post with the final solution so you can comment on it...

Comment: @alec_djinn: because what you posted before editing your comment showed that you are returning the *only value* you ever yield. Using `next()` on the generator would access that one value.

Answer (score 0):

`class` based approach

```
class FunctionAndGenerator:
    def __init__(self):
        self.counter = 0
        
    def __iter__(self):
        return self
        

# You need a variable to indicate if dunder next should return the string or raise StopIteration. 
# Raising StopIteration will stop the loop from iterating more.
# You'll have to teach next to raise StopIteration at some point

    def __next__(self):
        self.counter += 1 
        if self.counter > 1 :
            raise StopIteration 
        return f"I'm a generator and I've generated {self.counter} times"        

    def __call__(self):
        return "I'm a function"
        
x = FunctionAndGenerator()
print(x())
    
for i in x:
    print(i)
```

```
I'm a function
I'm a generator and I've generated 1 times

[Program finished]
```